# How to graph a function in Python using plotnine library

Tags: python, r, plot, ggplot2, plotnine

I've been a longtime R user, recently transitioning over to Python, and I've been trying to carry over my knowledge of plotting with ggplot2, since it is so intuitive. [Plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is supposedly the most ggplot2-esque plotting library, and I've successfully recreated most graphs with it, except critically how to plot regular functions.

In base R, you can easily define an eq., as in [so](http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/03/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-9-function-plots.html), input the result into a `stat_function()` layer, and set the limits of the graph in place of the `data` arg., and successfully plot a parabola or the like. However, the syntax for setting the graph's limits must be different in Python (perhaps using numpy?), and equations are defined using `sympy`, which is another divergence for me.

So how would I go about plotting functions with plotnine? The above two hurdles are the two differences with ggplot2 that I think are causing me trouble, since plotnine has so few examples online.

P.S. This is an example of what I want to recreate in Python using plotnine:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> basic_plot <- function(x) x^2 + 2.5
> graph <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-5,5)), aes(x=x)) +
+ stat_function(fun = basic_plot)
> graph
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? Maybe a [mcve] in R?

Comment: Sure, I just added an edit to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need numpy, it works just fine the "standard" way! :)

```
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd

(ggplot(pd.DataFrame(data={"x": [-5, 5]}), aes(x="x"))
    + stat_function(fun=lambda x: x**2+2.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the main differences that caused me problems was the same as posted in the question.  Specifically:

in R
    aes(x = x) or aes(x)

in plotnine
    aes(x = 'x')